# Copying file any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.sigdata to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.sigdata failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, f#, publish

I am having trouble publishing my Visual Studio C# Web Service. 
Builds fine, Runs fine, but when publishing I get this weird error:

> Copying file any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.sigdata to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.sigdata failed. Could not find file 'any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.sigdata'.

I have tried removing all Fsharp packages in the solution. Hard removing from packages directory. Adding the dependentAssembly to web.config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.1.0" newVersion="4.4.1.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**Package**

```
<package id="FSharp.Core" version="4.2.2" targetFramework="net462" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution. After a lot of work, I found that my webservice.csproj file had two lines in it that I had to remove.

```
<Content Include="any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.sigdata" />
<Content Include="any\netstandard1.6\FSharp.Core.optdata" />
```

I have not idea how they got there in the 1st place.